# SQL Server -> Postgres; Table Definition with Clustered Index

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I am switching from a SQL Server database to Postgres one, and have a series of table definitions that have clustered indexes. How do I convert them to Postgres?

**Note**: I have already converted the data types to ones that are supported by Postgres.

Here's a sample definition:

```
CREATE TABLE MESSAGES
(
    MESSAGE_ID int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
    MESSAGE varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    MESSAGE_TYPE varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    SENDER_ID varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    USERS xml NOT NULL,
    WORKGROUPS xml NOT NULL,
    PROFILES xml NOT NULL,
    CLEARED xml NOT NULL,
    START_DT timestamp NOT NULL,
    END_DT timestamp NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([MESSAGE_ID] ASC) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

Comment: Remove the clustered indexes.  That's all.  Also be sure the types are correct for Postgres.

Comment: `primary key (message_id)`